# Induction proof of $k$ homogeneous equations in $k+1$ variables have more than one solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have $k$ homogeneous linear equations in $k+1$ variables $x_1,\dots, x_{k+1}$ satisfying the assumption that the coefficient of $x_i$ in the $i$th equation is non-zero. Then by **Guassian elimination**, even without the coefficient assumption, we know the solution is not unique.

I am wondering is there an **inductive proof** of this fact?

For the base case when $k=1$, the equation is like
$$ax_1+bx_2=0$$
and $a\neq 0$.
Then we know the solution is not unique.

Comment: This is covered by Kronecker-Capelli theorem. There are $k+1 - \mathrm{rank}(A)$ free variables, which determines the dimension of the solution space (the kernel of the system matrix $A$).

Comment: I know the fact. I think the theorem is proved by Guassian elimination (row reduction of the coefficient matrix)? I am asking is there an inductive proof of the fact.

Comment: Didnt think it through, but it seems that you can simply solve the first equation for $x_1$ and plug it into the other $k$ equations... so you have $k$ equations in $k+1$ variables again.

Comment: I thought about induction too, but applying induction hypothesis (which is presumably that all systems with $n+1$ variables have nontrivial nullspace whenever the rank is $\leqslant n$ ) proves quite difficult. That is, when I try the substitution trick. Probably  missing something obvious.